# Backgammon board for 3 players

Tags: game-design, backgammon

I've been thinking about how backgammon might be extended to 3 or more players. Below is a mockup of my current idea of what the board might look like. The concept could technically be extended to any number of players, but it would be less and less fun with more players probably, because each player only encounters the checkers of the players on either side of him or her.

I'm excited to try this out with some friends but haven't been able to yet because of COVID-19. So for now I'm looking for feedback on problems that may make the game unworkable, or improvements to the board layout (the flow of the pieces is a little awkward but it's the best I've come up with so far).

[image]

Comment: This board is equivalent to others that already exist, but your layout uses unnecessary complication in the curves and the fact that the same colour is first on spikes pointing towards then away from the player.

Comment: You can playlets a game against your self by playing as all players.  That is helpful in early stages of design in finding problems.  Also whilst the pandemic is happening Online playlets groups are springing up all over, you should be able to google some.   I've done more play testing of my own game in the last month with strangers than I ever would get the chance normally.

Comment: @Nij Could you point me to some that exist? I had searched online but couldn’t find anything. Also I’m hoping to see an improved version of the board that doesn’t have that complication but I haven’t been able to think of something that avoids it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I mean it with all politeness, but a Google search for *3 player bac...* didn't autofill and give you exactly what you're asking about?

Comment: @Nij You have uncovered my problem... I have had DuckDuckGo as my default search engine and use it without thinking about it. And searching for that on DDG does not show anything related to 3 player backgammon until the 18th result.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like these have already been done, and done well:

[Trigammon](https://sethares.engr.wisc.edu/games/trigammon.html)

[Quadgammon](https://sethares.engr.wisc.edu/games/quadgammon.html)

The Quadgammon board is very cleverly designed!

Answer (score 0):

A four-player version (with a different board layout where you meet all other opponents) already exists:

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17769/quatro-gammon